# SOAP : build envelope in php

Tags: php, soap

I want to achieve this xml.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://eid.equifax.com/soap/schema/canada/v2">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v2:InitialRequest>
     <v2:Identity>
        <v2:Name>
           <v2:FirstName>MILO</v2:FirstName>
           <v2:LastName>TESTADD</v2:LastName>
        </v2:Name>
        <!--1 to 3 repetitions:-->
        <v2:Address timeAtAddress="50" addressType="Current">
           <v2:HybridAddress>
              <v2:AddressLine>731 BAY AVE</v2:AddressLine>
              <v2:City>Kelowna</v2:City>
              <v2:Province>BC</v2:Province>
              <v2:PostalCode>V1Y7K2</v2:PostalCode>
           </v2:HybridAddress>
        </v2:Address>
        <v2:DateOfBirth>
           <v2:Day>03</v2:Day>
           <v2:Month>03</v2:Month>
           <v2:Year>1989</v2:Year>
        </v2:DateOfBirth>
     </v2:Identity>
     <v2:ProcessingOptions>
        <v2:Language>English</v2:Language>
     </v2:ProcessingOptions>
  </v2:InitialRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, far I have created this:

```
$all_names = array('FirstName'=>"PERFUME",
                       'LastName'=>"TESTSWEET");
    $all_addresses = array('AddressLine'=>"109 ALBERT ST NE",
                           'City'=>"AIRDRIE",
                           'Province'=>"AB",
                           'PostalCode'=>"T4B0R5"
                           );
    $hybrid_address = array('HybridAddress'=>$all_addresses);
    $dob = array('Day'=>"31",
                 'Month'=>"09",
                 'Year'=>"1972"
                 );
    $identity = array('Name'=>$all_names,
                      'Address'=>$hybrid_address,
                      'DateOfBirth'=>$dob
                      );
    $language = array('Language'=>'English');
    $initial_request = array('Identity'=>$identity,
                             'ProcessingOptions'=>$language
                             );

$test = $client->__call('startTransaction', array('initialRequest'=>$initial_request));
```

But, I don't know, what's wrong in here. It's giving me internal server error.

PS: Data seems different, b'coz I copied from different source.

**EDIT**

```
[14-May-2015 17:02:03 America/Toronto] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault     exception: [soap:Server] Unexpected internal error in     D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\third_party\WSSoapClient.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\third_party\WSSoapClient.php(61): SoapClient->__call('startTransactio...', Array)
#1 D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\controllers\equifax.php(58): WSSoapClient->__call('startTransactio...', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Equifax->verify()
#3 D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php(227): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...')
#5 {main}
thrown in D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\third_party\WSSoapClient.php on     line 61
```

Comment: Anything in the error logs to narrow it down? Is error reporting on?

Comment: Yeah. It's on. Check my edit please.

Comment: @chris85: Because of this I can not even use this function to get last request: `__getLastRequest()`

Comment: LEt me know if need `wsdl` link

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get equifax working now for a couple weeks. 
The support line is next to useless.

Have you set the encoding? It's meant to be UTF8.
Also getting the namespace in the envelope right also stops some errors.
It's changed from the documentation, which is full of typos and out of date.

The way the header is included is also a little tempremental and not as per the documentation

Comment: Can you please create different question and try to elaborate yourself and if possible show some code snippet with errors you are getting.